# Javah -stubs не генерирует ничего

Tags: java, c++, jni, native

Пробую JNI, наткнулся на такую статью: [ссылка](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077513/learn-java/java-tip-17--integrating-java-with-c--.html) 
Там автор пишет такое:

> To write the C functions, we run javah twice, first as "javah NumberListProxy," then as "javah -stubs NumberListProxy." This automatically generates some "glue" code needed for the Java runtime (which it puts in NumberListProxy.c) and generates declarations for the C functions that we are to implement (in NumberListProxy.h).

Я пробую повторить описанное и `javah -stubs` не генерирует

> NumberListProxy.c

Он только создает заголовочный файл который не отличается от созданного без флага `-stubs`

Вопрос в том что это я где то делаю неправильно или причина в другом ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы запустите `javah` с ключом `-h`, то увидите, что ключа `-stub` нет в списке. Он давно убран. Утилита не ругается на его использование только для того, чтобы не ломать старые сценарии сборки.

Comment: В консоли нет справки, но на сайте oracle я нашел этот флаг. Хотя похоже что вы правы, спасибо

Comment: Oracle - лентяи, у них таких косяков в онлайн-справке просто завал :)